# Testing whether a certain type of non-null element exists... somewhere

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML that looks like

```
<answers>
   <answer>
      <question-number>1</question-number>
      <value>3</value>
      <mean xsi:nil="1" />
    </answer>
   <answer>
      <question-number>2</question-number>
      <value>2</value>
      <mean>2.3</mean>
    </answer>
   <answer>
      <question-number>3</question-number>
      <value>3</value>
      <mean xsi:nil="1" />
    </answer>
....
</answers>
```

I'm formatting each answer using xsl:for-each.  If there is a mean present I have a graphical representation of the mean.  For some potential lists of answers the mean will always be null.

At the bottom of the page I want to put a legend explaining the graphical representation of the mean.  But I only want it to appear if I actually displayed a mean at all.  So I want to be able to do a check, after closing the xsl:for-each, to say "do any of the answer elements have a non-null mean value?".

Really not sure how to do that.

Comment: Why do you have a mean element when there is no mean? Surely it would make more sense for the entire attribute to be absent in the case of a lack of a mean, rather than assigning an arbitrary 'null' value to it.

Comment: Fair point.  I'll try to attack it from that direction too, but that's the XML that's being generated by the serializer this project used (before my time).  xsi:nil is meant to be used to indicate that an element that's not usually empty is meant to be empty.  Maybe I can turn that off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what finally worked for me:

```
<xsl:if test="//answers/answer/mean>0">
```

That is to say, "do there exist any answer elements for which the mean value is greater than zero".  Fortunately I know that the mean value, if there is one, will in fact always be greater than zero -- unfortunately this isn't a generalized solution for this reason.

I still think the approach that jasper and workmad3 were taking (checking for the xsi:nil attribute) ought to work, but I couldn't get the syntax to actually... work.

Many thanks, all.

Answer (score 5):

do any of the answer elements have a non-null mean value?
based on roberts example

```
<xs:if test="(count(/answers/answer/mean[not(@xsi:nil)])>0"><xs:if>
```

EDIT:

```
<xs:if test="//answer/mean[not(text())]"><xs:if>
```

LAST EDIT (before going home...)

```
<xs:if test="//answer/mean[attribute::xsi:nil]"><xs:if>
```

Comment: makes sense to me -- good restatement of my question -- but in fact it's never displaying when using that test.

Comment: The second one you posted -- not(//answer/mean/text()) -- seems to return true all the time.

Comment: I see the second one was copy-pasted from the wrong page ;). The (now) second and third should give you the same nodeset.

Comment: Try this http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm for testing the expressions. Also supports namespaces

Answer (score 2):

```
<xs:if test="count(/answers/answer/mean[@xsi:nil != '1']) > 0">Mean stuff here</xs:if>
```

Should do what you want (count the means where the xsi:nil attribute isn't set to 1)

Comment: Hmm.  As with Jasper's, this makes sense and ought to work, but it's never displaying (i.e. never returning true, even if some of the mean elements have a numeric value).  I shall keep exploring this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. if you have any means it will return true

```
<xs:if test="/answers/answer/mean">You have a mean</xs:if>
```

I think this is what you mean.

Edit: maybe this?

```
<xs:if test="(count(/answers/answer/mean)==1)">You have a mean<xs:if>
```

Not sure if this works, but it might

```
<xs:if test="/answers/answer/mean != nil">You have a mean</xs:if>
```

Comment: This appears to be checking whether there is any element called mean, whether it's null or not.  In my XML example above, if all of the "mean" elements had xsi:nil="1", then I don't want to display,  Thanks, though!

Comment: Maybe I could check for the existence of an "element" one level below the mean -- like test="answers/answer/mean/*"?  I'll try that.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to display ever.

Comment: This test that you added -- "(count(/answers/answer/mean)==1)" -- resulted in this error: "A location path was expected, but the following token was encountered:  ="

Comment: And the next one you added -- "/answers/answer/mean != nil" -- seems to result in never displaying.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
  <xsl:for-each select="/answers/answer">
      <xsl:if test="mean &gt;= 0">
          ... other code ...
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Won't this cause my legend to display once for every time there's a non-null mean?  I want it to display once, only, if there are any non-null means at all, and otherwise not display.

Comment: Yes, you'd want this outside your for-each loop, as you have in your answer below.